# Problem about using semantic-rules with space trems

Tags: vespa

We reference https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/semantic-rules.html

When we set the statement like this:

```
i7 +> ?"iphone 7";
```

It works.

However, when we are trying to state like this:

```
iphone 7 +> ?i7;
```

It fails when we searched it.

Do you have any advice about setting the term with space?

Comment: Maybe you could add some more context to your question? E.g how does it fail? Do  you get an error or simply that the rule does no trigger? If you add &tracelevel.rule=5 you'll get a trace of the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special is needed to handle space since the rules match multiple consecutive terms by default. If you want to match with gaps you need to add a "...", e.g "iphone ... 7". So

iphone 7 +> ?i7;

will rewrite a query containing the consecutive terms 'iphone' and '7' to 
"OR (AND iphone 7) i7" - i.e it will match documents containing either "iphone 7" or "i7".

You can see this by adding &tracelevel=3 to the query url.

Answer (score 0):

is any issue abount utf-8 term not english term ?

we are using vespa in Taiwan, use Traditional Chinese terms.

we found that iphone 7 +> ?EnglishTerm  is OK
but iphone 7 +> ?ChineseTerm is not work for us